# Angular Js 7 overwrite the azure Web Api url with it own Base Url

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router, azure-web-app-service

I have two separate web applications hosted in the Azure web app.

One is based on angular js 8 front-end and the other is backend .net core web API 2.2.

I have created a basic method to call values from web API which returns value1, and values 2, similarly some other API method is there which return me json.

If I call in browser https://B.azurewebsites.net/api/values which return me value1 and value 2 successfully.

Now my front end angular web application is trying to call the web api in the local machine running over http://localhost:4200 and calling the azure hosted web api like below

```
export class ApiDataService 
{
private REST_API_SERVER = "";  //mentioned in constant file under services


  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
     this.REST_API_SERVER = "https://B.azurewebsites.net/api";
  }


public getList() {
    return this.httpClient.get(this.REST_API_SERVER + 
     "/employee/getlist").pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
  }
```

In local machine, it is running good.

While deploying the angular web app In Azure It is throwing error 404 with message :

## #

http:failure response for https://A.azurewebsites.net/B.azurewebsites.net/api/employee/getlist

## #

In here A.azurewebsites.net -> Angular web app

B.azurewebsites.net -> .Net Core Web api 2.2

I am not able to find any reason why the azurewebsites calling two times 
it should call simply https://B.azurewebsites.net/api/employee/getlist

I also removed the "/" from index.html in angular project like

```
<base href=""/> --removed the "/"
```

How to reset the base url in the employee.component.ts

Any Suggestions or comments Will be very helpful.

Comment: Are you using some sort of environment variable to set `this.REST_API_SERVER` or is the value actually hard coded as shown? Looks like the protocol is missing for some reason and so browser looks at it as a relative url which is why you get the combined urls like that. Log that variable before request gets made and make sure the protocol is in the string

Comment: @charlietfl yes I have tried with hardcoded value it is overwriting while deployed in azure but in local same hardcoded value is working fine. Now I think I need to look at how to set the angular base URL for the Http client. Don't know why this is happening only in azure

Comment: In the angular js index.html there is mentioned <base href="/"> I have tried to remove the line but same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to create a class that is derived from HTTPClient and set the base URL there like below:

```
@Injectable()
export class ApiHttpClient extends HttpClient {
  public baseUrl: string;

  public constructor(handler: HttpHandler,
    private constName: ConstNameService ) {
    super(handler);

    // Get base url from wherever you like, or provision ApiHttpClient in your AppComponent or some other high level
    // component and set the baseUrl there.
    this.baseUrl = constName.apilocalUrl.prod_api_url;//'/api/';
  }

  public getMethod(url: string, options?: Object): Observable<any> {
    url = this.baseUrl + url;
    return super.get(url, options);
  }
}
```

Now Using this class in a service module to get the data list

```
constructor(private constName: ConstNameService,
    private apiclient :ApiHttpClient ) {}


  public getEmpList() {
   this.apiclient.getMethod("/employee/getlist").pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
  }
```